# visiting a dynamic link that opened in new tab in cypress

Tags: automated-testing, cypress

Scenario:

While clicking a link/button in the application, a new tab is opened (with a dynamic url)

Is there a way in cypress to test somethings in the newly opened tab?

I cannot use `cy.visit()` as the url generated will be different each time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Cypress official documentation, this is not supported: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs.html#Multiple-tabs

Perhaps you can test that the link has some particular attributes:

```
cy.get('a[href="/foo"]').should('have.attr', 'target', '_blank')
```

or you can follow this: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/testing-dom__tab-handling-links

> - Test anchor links opening in new tabs: .
> - Test anchor links that link to external domains: .
> - Prevent content from opening in a new tab.
> - Request external content that would open in a new tab using cy.request().
> - Speed up tests by reducing loading times.

But there is no way you can switch to a newly opened tab like many Testers are used to from Selenium.

Comment: ohh k. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround to test the links that open in new tabs.
You can open it in the same window. Here is the sample code for that:

For example, in case of below html:

`<a id="abc" class="btn-style" href="http://www.xyz.com/" target="_blank">example</a>`

Now, let's assume that in above case the url value for attribute `href` changes every time.

You can check it using below code. It will open this link in the same window (if that's ok with you.)

`cy.get('abc').then (function(ln)
{
    const url= ln.prop('href')
    cy.vist(url)
})`